# Why isn't explicit specialization with private type allowed for function templates?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

https://godbolt.org/z/s5Yh8e6b8

I don't understand the reasoning behind this: why is explicit specialization with private type allowed for class templates but not for function templates?

Say we have a class:

```
class pepe
{
    struct lolo
    {
        std::string name = "lolo";
    };
public:
    static lolo get()
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

- Class template can be explicitly specialized.
- And function templates have no problems upon implicit instantiation.
- Though you can't create `spec_class<pepe::lolo>{}` because `pepe::lolo` is inaccessable.

```
template <typename>
struct spec_class
{};

// this is ok
template <>
struct spec_class<pepe::lolo>
{};

// this will be ok also upon implicit instantiation
template <typename T>
void template_func(const T &t)
{
    std::cout << "implicit: " << t.name << std::endl;
}
```

But:

```
// this is not ok!
// template <>
// void template_func(const pepe::lolo &p)
// {
//     std::cout << "explicit: " << p.name << std::endl;
// }

// this is ok, but more or less understandable why
template <>
void template_func(const decltype(pepe::get()) &p)
{
    std::cout << "explicit: " << p.name << std::endl;
}

// not ok, but expected
// void func(const pepe::lolo&)
// {}
```

So:
**Why is explicit specialization prohibited for a function template?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From C++20, using private members in the parameter of a specialization of a function template is perfectly valid, due to [PR0692](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0692r1.html). In particular, the following wording was added to [temp.spec.general#6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.general#6):

> **The usual access checking rules do not apply to names in a declaration of an explicit instantiation or explicit specialization**, with the exception of names appearing in a function body, default argument, *base-clause*, *member-specification*, *enumerator-list*, or static data member or variable template initializer.
>
> [ *Note 1:* In particular, the template arguments and names used in the function declarator (including **parameter types**, return types and exception specifications) can be private types or objects that would normally not be accessible. - *end note*]

(emphasis mine)

The code not compiling is due to a [GCC bug 97942](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97942), and it compiles just fine in Clang. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E835TeKxd).